# PHP | Add elements to the array and sort after loop

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to get some numeric values ​​out, recovered thanks to: `wp_get_post_terms`, which retrieves me the daughter taxonomies of customized taxonomies, where prices are inserted in them in numerical form.

The goal is to display prices using sort and rsort, in the order decided.

When recovering the values, however, I am wrong to add elements to the array and sort them later

code:

```
foreach ($qprice as $r)
    {
        $children = $r->term_id;
        $child_terms = get_term_children($r->term_id, 'servizi_pro');
        $all_terms   = wp_get_post_terms($r->ID, 'servizi_pro');


        foreach ( $all_terms as $term )
        {

            if (!in_array($term->term_id, $child_terms))
                continue;

            
            $price = $term->name;

            $final_price = [$price];
        }


        rsort($final_price, SORT_NUMERIC);
        foreach($final_price as $pr_f) {
            echo '<span  class="numberCircle"><span>'.str_pad($pr_f, 9).''.'€'.'</span></span>';
        }
    }
```

plus:

```
  $final_price = [];
foreach ($qprice as $r)
{
    $children = $r->term_id;
    $child_terms = get_term_children($r->term_id, 'servizi_pro');
    $all_terms   = wp_get_post_terms($r->ID, 'servizi_pro');

    foreach ( $all_terms as $term )
    {
        if (!in_array($term->term_id, $child_terms))
            continue;

        $price = $term->name;
        $final_price[] = $price;
    }
}

sort($final_price, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach($final_price as $pr_f) {
    echo '<span  class="numberCircle"><span>'.str_pad($pr_f, 9).'€'.'</span></span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the `$final_price` array before the inner `foreach` loop, and push onto the array rather than replacing it each time through the loop.

```
foreach ($qprice as $r)
{
    $children = $r->term_id;
    $child_terms = get_term_children($r->term_id, 'servizi_pro');
    $all_terms   = wp_get_post_terms($r->ID, 'servizi_pro');

    $final_price = [];
    foreach ( $all_terms as $term )
    {

        if (!in_array($term->term_id, $child_terms))
            continue;

        $price = $term->name;
        $final_price[] = $price;
    }

    rsort($final_price, SORT_NUMERIC);
    foreach($final_price as $pr_f) {
        echo '<span  class="numberCircle"><span>'.str_pad($pr_f, 9).''.'€'.'</span></span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! but if I change the instruction from rsort to sort it doesn't sort them out as sort should do, why?

Comment: That should sort them, just in the opposite order.

Comment: yes yes, I probably wrote it wrong, your code is perfectly functional and I thank you obviously rsort gives me from the most expensive price to the least expensive, but replacing your rsort code with sort, it does not order them from the least to the most expensive , I was wondering why

Comment: I can't think of any good reason why that would happen. Did you keep `SORT_NUMERIC`?

Comment: yes: sort($final_price, SORT_NUMERIC);
        foreach($final_price as $pr_f) {
            echo '<span  class="numberCircle"><span>'.str_pad($pr_f, 9).''.'€'.'</span></span>';
        }

Comment: but i have in this order: 1600 €
800 €
750 €

Comment: I can't think of any reason for that.

Comment: Make sure you're actually running the version with the change. Watch out for browser caching.

Comment: yes, I also performed more hard refresh but nothing

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, so the problem is somewhere else. Sorry.

Comment: I added a piece to the question: "plus", running the print_r, I don't understand why the result I wrote in the question always comes out Array [0] and not 1, 2

Comment: Nothing in the loop is changing `$final_price`, it makes no sense that `print_r($final_price)` would change each time.

Comment: another user suggested this (update plus my question) to me and now sort and rsort work fine, the only thing that being the second foreach outside the first I can't access the post values ​​and therefore it's useless, how can I do to get the same result but inside $qprice ?

Comment: You weren't accessing the post values in the original code, so why is that a problem?

Comment: I don't know what any of this data represents or how it's organized, so I can't help you with the overall structure of your code. As the programmer, that's your job, you shouldn't need all this spoon-fed to you.

Comment: instead yes, because that foreach gives me access to be able to create the professional card, the ordering of prices was to order the cards of the professionals in display, but now I find myself with the amounts that are sorted by sort or rsort, but I don't have access to the post values, because the second foreach is outside the first, but if I insert the second inside the first, sort no longer works

Comment: `sort` works the same inside an inner loop as outside. The only difference is whether you're combining the prices all the children into the array or just showing the prices of a single element of `$qprice`.

Comment: I just realized that the different `print_r()` are coming from iterations of the outer loop, not the inner loop. So the problem is that there's just one `$final_price` for each element of `$qprice`, and there's nothing to sort in the inner loop.